# Motion WebCam USB Errors - Unable to open Video Device

Tags: usb-power, motion

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2 with a Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000 connecting running Motion for a Webcam. I am getting periodic errors on the Webcam and it stops working. I am using a 2.5Amp power supply as I was getting low voltage messages but that is all resolved but I am still having problems. Looking at the syslog there are lots of messages/errors but I can't honestly see the wood for the trees. Any help would be gratefully received.

Syslog

```
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.223623] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.223667] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.223683] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.224122] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.224215] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.247967] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.266742] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.267562] rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(1) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 482
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.304979] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306214] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 959 at net/wireless/sme.c:1060 __cfg80211_disconnected+0x358/0x3a0 [cfg80211]
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306231] Modules linked in: evdev 8192cu sha256_generic cfg80211 snd_usb_audio snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib uvcvideo rfkill snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device raspberrypi_hwmon hwmon snd_bcm2835(C) snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) v4l2_mem2mem bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) v4l2_common videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev media vc_sm_cma(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio fixed ip_tables x_tables ipv6
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306425] CPU: 0 PID: 959 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G         C        4.19.42+ #1219
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306431] Hardware name: BCM2835
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306471] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306526] [<c0017e54>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0014d9c>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306565] [<c0014d9c>] (show_stack) from [<c06afcf0>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306603] [<c06afcf0>] (dump_stack) from [<c0024388>] (__warn+0xf4/0x11c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.306628] [<c0024388>] (__warn) from [<c00244e0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x4c/0x58)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.307764] [<c00244e0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf2e981c>] (__cfg80211_disconnected+0x358/0x3a0 [cfg80211])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.309901] [<bf2e981c>] (__cfg80211_disconnected [cfg80211]) from [<bf2bcf5c>] (cfg80211_process_wdev_events+0x160/0x1c8 [cfg80211])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.311989] [<bf2bcf5c>] (cfg80211_process_wdev_events [cfg80211]) from [<bf2b9b60>] (cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3b4/0x610 [cfg80211])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313073] [<bf2b9b60>] (cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call [cfg80211]) from [<c0044608>] (notifier_call_chain+0x54/0x94)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313113] [<c0044608>] (notifier_call_chain) from [<c00447c0>] (raw_notifier_call_chain+0x28/0x30)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313152] [<c00447c0>] (raw_notifier_call_chain) from [<c059d3b8>] (call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x3c/0x8c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313187] [<c059d3b8>] (call_netdevice_notifiers_info) from [<c05a19d8>] (rollback_registered_many+0x2c4/0x4dc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313214] [<c05a19d8>] (rollback_registered_many) from [<c05a1c34>] (rollback_registered+0x44/0x74)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313421] [<c05a1c34>] (rollback_registered) from [<c05a1cd0>] (unregister_netdevice_queue+0x6c/0xec)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.313451] [<c05a1cd0>] (unregister_netdevice_queue) from [<c05a1d78>] (unregister_netdev+0x28/0x30)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.314226] [<c05a1d78>] (unregister_netdev) from [<bf3d0948>] (rtw_unregister_netdevs+0x54/0x74 [8192cu])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315235] [<bf3d0948>] (rtw_unregister_netdevs [8192cu]) from [<bf3d186c>] (rtw_dev_remove+0x2c/0x7c [8192cu])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315743] [<bf3d186c>] (rtw_dev_remove [8192cu]) from [<c04c2d54>] (usb_unbind_interface+0x7c/0x25c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315777] [<c04c2d54>] (usb_unbind_interface) from [<c04574f8>] (device_release_driver_internal+0x188/0x228)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315799] [<c04574f8>] (device_release_driver_internal) from [<c04575b8>] (device_release_driver+0x20/0x24)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315836] [<c04575b8>] (device_release_driver) from [<c0455f04>] (bus_remove_device+0xd8/0x108)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315862] [<c0455f04>] (bus_remove_device) from [<c0452780>] (device_del+0x128/0x340)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315887] [<c0452780>] (device_del) from [<c04c0524>] (usb_disable_device+0xb0/0x1e0)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315924] [<c04c0524>] (usb_disable_device) from [<c04b6aa0>] (usb_disconnect+0x7c/0x1fc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315950] [<c04b6aa0>] (usb_disconnect) from [<c04b6bd8>] (usb_disconnect+0x1b4/0x1fc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.315977] [<c04b6bd8>] (usb_disconnect) from [<c04b85a0>] (hub_event+0x5b8/0x11f4)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316011] [<c04b85a0>] (hub_event) from [<c003d108>] (process_one_work+0x130/0x3a0)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316036] [<c003d108>] (process_one_work) from [<c003d3ac>] (worker_thread+0x34/0x530)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316058] [<c003d3ac>] (worker_thread) from [<c0042eb0>] (kthread+0x11c/0x158)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316081] [<c0042eb0>] (kthread) from [<c00090ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316091] Exception stack(0xda4c7fb0 to 0xda4c7ff8)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316105] 7fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316121] 7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316133] 7fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316145] ---[ end trace 7ff3149d1de98a1b ]---
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.316158] ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317343] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 959 at net/wireless/core.c:1331 cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3cc/0x610 [cfg80211]
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317356] Modules linked in: evdev 8192cu sha256_generic cfg80211 snd_usb_audio snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib uvcvideo rfkill snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device raspberrypi_hwmon hwmon snd_bcm2835(C) snd_pcm snd_timer snd bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) v4l2_mem2mem bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) v4l2_common videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev media vc_sm_cma(C) uio_pdrv_genirq uio fixed ip_tables x_tables ipv6
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317548] CPU: 0 PID: 959 Comm: kworker/0:2 Tainted: G        WC        4.19.42+ #1219
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317554] Hardware name: BCM2835
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317595] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317647] [<c0017e54>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0014d9c>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317687] [<c0014d9c>] (show_stack) from [<c06afcf0>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317725] [<c06afcf0>] (dump_stack) from [<c0024388>] (__warn+0xf4/0x11c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.317751] [<c0024388>] (__warn) from [<c00244e0>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x4c/0x58)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.318890] [<c00244e0>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<bf2b9b78>] (cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x3cc/0x610 [cfg80211])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320002] [<bf2b9b78>] (cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call [cfg80211]) from [<c0044608>] (notifier_call_chain+0x54/0x94)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320042] [<c0044608>] (notifier_call_chain) from [<c00447c0>] (raw_notifier_call_chain+0x28/0x30)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320081] [<c00447c0>] (raw_notifier_call_chain) from [<c059d3b8>] (call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x3c/0x8c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320115] [<c059d3b8>] (call_netdevice_notifiers_info) from [<c05a19d8>] (rollback_registered_many+0x2c4/0x4dc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320143] [<c05a19d8>] (rollback_registered_many) from [<c05a1c34>] (rollback_registered+0x44/0x74)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320168] [<c05a1c34>] (rollback_registered) from [<c05a1cd0>] (unregister_netdevice_queue+0x6c/0xec)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320192] [<c05a1cd0>] (unregister_netdevice_queue) from [<c05a1d78>] (unregister_netdev+0x28/0x30)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.320967] [<c05a1d78>] (unregister_netdev) from [<bf3d0948>] (rtw_unregister_netdevs+0x54/0x74 [8192cu])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.321938] [<bf3d0948>] (rtw_unregister_netdevs [8192cu]) from [<bf3d186c>] (rtw_dev_remove+0x2c/0x7c [8192cu])
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322452] [<bf3d186c>] (rtw_dev_remove [8192cu]) from [<c04c2d54>] (usb_unbind_interface+0x7c/0x25c)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322484] [<c04c2d54>] (usb_unbind_interface) from [<c04574f8>] (device_release_driver_internal+0x188/0x228)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322506] [<c04574f8>] (device_release_driver_internal) from [<c04575b8>] (device_release_driver+0x20/0x24)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322544] [<c04575b8>] (device_release_driver) from [<c0455f04>] (bus_remove_device+0xd8/0x108)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322570] [<c0455f04>] (bus_remove_device) from [<c0452780>] (device_del+0x128/0x340)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322594] [<c0452780>] (device_del) from [<c04c0524>] (usb_disable_device+0xb0/0x1e0)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322631] [<c04c0524>] (usb_disable_device) from [<c04b6aa0>] (usb_disconnect+0x7c/0x1fc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322658] [<c04b6aa0>] (usb_disconnect) from [<c04b6bd8>] (usb_disconnect+0x1b4/0x1fc)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322685] [<c04b6bd8>] (usb_disconnect) from [<c04b85a0>] (hub_event+0x5b8/0x11f4)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322720] [<c04b85a0>] (hub_event) from [<c003d108>] (process_one_work+0x130/0x3a0)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322745] [<c003d108>] (process_one_work) from [<c003d3ac>] (worker_thread+0x34/0x530)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322768] [<c003d3ac>] (worker_thread) from [<c0042eb0>] (kthread+0x11c/0x158)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322790] [<c0042eb0>] (kthread) from [<c00090ac>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x28)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322801] Exception stack(0xda4c7fb0 to 0xda4c7ff8)
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322814] 7fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322830] 7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322842] 7fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
May 20 16:32:35 armstrong kernel: [13105.322853] ---[ end trace 7ff3149d1de98a1c ]---
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong kernel: [13105.643662] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001501
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 0:0:0:0:0.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: carrier lost
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 0.0.0.0.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Withdrawing address record for 0:0:0:0:0 on wlan0.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Withdrawing address record for 0.0.0.0 on wlan0.
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong kernel: [13106.163480] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
May 20 16:32:36 armstrong kernel: [13106.163736] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13106.593940] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13106.593986] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13106.600098] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13106.600279] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: deleting address 0:0:0:0:0
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.0.1
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: deleting route to 192.168.0.0/24
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13106.933553] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: eth0: removing interface
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.063982] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.064008] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.071301] smsc95xx v1.0.6
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.193522] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:c4:5d:b8
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1"
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: removing interface
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.293492] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.440642] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0779, bcdDevice= 1.06
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.440669] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.440682] usb 1-1.4: Product: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.440695] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.453659] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000 (045e:0779)
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.476748] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 5 was not initialized!
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.476779] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 4 was not initialized!
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.476795] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Selector 3 was not initialized!
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.476809] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
May 20 16:32:37 armstrong kernel: [13107.477542] input: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000: Mi as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input1
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.713553] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong dhcpcd-run-hooks[1027]: wlan0: stopping wpa_supplicant
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.845893] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=7811, bcdDevice= 2.00
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.845919] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.845930] usb 1-1.5: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.845943] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Realtek
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong kernel: [13107.845954] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
May 20 16:32:38 armstrong mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
May 20 16:32:39 armstrong mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
May 20 16:32:39 armstrong mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
May 20 16:32:39 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May 20 16:32:39 armstrong kernel: [13109.245130] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May 20 16:32:39 armstrong kernel: [13109.246285] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
May 20 16:32:40 armstrong systemd-udevd[1046]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
May 20 16:32:40 armstrong dhcpcd-run-hooks[1071]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 20 16:32:42 armstrong kernel: [13111.507156] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 20 16:32:42 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong kernel: [13113.339182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: carrier acquired
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: IAID 38:58:69:b5
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: adding address 0:0:0:0:0
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 0:0:0:0:0.
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 20 16:32:43 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Registering new address record for 0:0:0:0:0 on wlan0.*.
May 20 16:32:44 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 20 16:32:44 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 0.0.0.0
May 20 16:32:44 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: probing address 0.0.0.0/24
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: leased 0.0.0.0 for 864000 seconds
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 0.0.0.0.
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong avahi-daemon[231]: Registering new address record for 0.0.0.0 on wlan0.IPv4.
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
May 20 16:32:49 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
May 20 16:32:57 armstrong dhcpcd[375]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Comment: which OS/kernel are you running? what are the outputs of `lsusb` and `dmesg` when the errors appear?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I have now resolved the issue by upgrading my PI to a 4B with 4GB. From my research it seems that the 4B has better power overall and better USB power management. It now runs for days and weeks without issue.